# Does the following code have a memory leak?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
    Dictionary<string, Setup> dictSetups = new Dictionary<string, Setup>();
    Setup setup1 = new Setup();
    dictSetups.Add("setup1", setup1);

    using (MySetupForm myForm = new MySetupForm())
    {
        myForm.Setup = dictSetups["setup1"];
        if (myForm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            dictSetups["setup1"] = myForm.Setup;
        }                
    }
```

This is `MySetupForm`:

```
    public partial class MySetupForm : Form
    {
        public MySetupForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Setup Setup { get; set; }
    }
```

In the code above I am passing a reference of `dictSetups["setup1"]` to `MySetupForm` and then showing the form.

If the dialog result is `OK` I am updating the reference in my dictionary, my question is when I go out of using that means `MySetupForm myForm` is disposed, but

`dictSetups["setup1"]`  is holding reference from `myForm.Setup;` , so will it be a memory leak or not ?

Comment: What is `myForm.Setup`?  Is it a string, a reference to a `Form`, or what?

Comment: ....aaaand that's why I *hate* managed languages. Those good old days when programmers were programmers and they had to learn using malloc and free...

Comment: @H2CO3 In my day the programmers tapped out the 1's and 0's by hand and we liked it.

Comment: @asawyer I can understand you...

Comment: This is not strictly speaking a "leak", as there is still a handy dandy reference you have access to that you could use to release the memory. However, the memory will continue to be consumed until the dictionary is cleaned up. The entire form will not be held, just the "Setup" reference

Answer (score 2):

It's nearly impossible to tell for sure by the code you posted.

You should get a hold of a memory profiling tool and profile your application. That is the only real way to know if there is a memory leak, where it is, and the best way to fix it.

Comment: You can be 100% sure that there is no memory leak caused by the posted code.

Comment: @Servy - Do you know what scope the dictionary is defined in and when both the form and the dictionary are released?

Comment: @Servy How is that?  We don't even know whether `Dictionary<string, Setup> dictSetups = new Dictionary<string, Setup>();` is a local variable or a field.

Comment: @JustinNiessner We can know that whenever it is released the GC will take care of releasing its memory.

Comment: @Servy - But if things are being referenced other places and those references are being held on indefinitely, the GC will never release the memory and clean it up properly...hence the leak.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Holding onto the references of things that you don't need is indeed bad memory management, but it's not really a memory leak in my mind.  The general discussion aside, what's your basis for assuming that this section of code is holding onto a reference to something that isn't needed?  Is it possible that the OP is doing all sorts of bad things in code not shown that wastes lots of memory, sure.  Anything could be in large blocks of unknown code.  Is there any problem with what we can see of the code here, no.  Nor do I see any reason to assume there is a likely problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, yes. This has a memory leak, **in the context of code provided**. 
What I mean by this is that `Dictionary<string, Setup> dictSetups`  is global variable, that maintains its constant lifetime during application workflow.

In general, just from the code porvided, from  the *program* context point of view, it's hard to say.

Comment: A memory leak is when an object has gone out of scope, thus preventing the release of it's memory, on an object for which the memory must be manually released.  This is virtually impossible in C# because the garbage collector takes care of reclaiming memory for you.  The program may be less memory efficient if it is holding onto references to objects with a large memory footprint when they are no longer needed, but it's not actually a memory *leak*.

Comment: @Servy I think it's well established that "memory leak" in the context of the .NET garbage collector can mean "retaining references to objects after they are no longer needed, preventing their collection."

Comment: @phoog And what's your basis for assuming that the reference object is no longer needed?

Comment: @Servy I assume that the object is no longer needed because the developer has called `Dispose`.

Comment: @phoog There is no reference to the `Form` that is held onto, just a reference tot he `Setup` object.  That is presumably not disposed and could very well be usable.  Do you have some reason for assuming that `Setup` hold a reference to the form and will attempt to use it after it's disposed?

Comment: @Servy true -- I misread the code and thought that the form was being added to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

There is no memory leak here.

When you say `dictSetups["setup1"] = myForm.Setup;` you are fetching the `Setup` object that `myForm` was referencing and storing a reference to *that* in the dictionary.  It's not holding onto a reference to `myForm`.  There would need to be a lambda or something along those lines to generate a closure for that to happen.

A memory leak is when an object has gone out of scope, thus preventing the release of it's memory, on an object for which the memory must be manually released. This is virtually impossible in C# because the garbage collector takes care of reclaiming memory for you. The program may be less memory efficient if it is holding onto references to objects with a large memory footprint when they are no longer needed (there is no way for us to tell if you're doing this in your code; we can't know what objects you'll actually need references to later and which you wont), but it's not actually a memory leak.

While it is *possible* to cause a memory leak in C#, it's *really* hard.  You practically have to be actively trying to cause one for it to happen outside of a few narrow scopes.  If you're interoping with unmanaged code then you may need to deal with the memory management of that code, and if you're in unsafe blocks you can cause all sorts of havok.  Short of that, there's not really much you can do to cause a memory leak.  You can't usually allocate memory in C# that the garbage collector can't reclaim, and I know of no bugs that prevent the GC from reclaiming memory when it should.